# Get all values when button is pressed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the scenario, I have few list items which are repeat via ng-repeat. When we click on the submit button, I need to get all the information of the selected radio button (id, name and description). I know we can achieve this using ng-change on radio buttons, but it does not fulfill my requirement. I need to get it when the submit button is clicked.

Here is the link to plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YKtWm8kaLOIUfc09ZSCA?p=preview

```
 <form ng-submit="showData()">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="list in lists">
          <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" ng-model="radioMod.value" value="{{list.id}}">
              {{list.name}}
              <br />
          <p>{{list.description}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

I have added nothing to the controller...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.lists = [
    {"id": 1, 'name' : 'radio1', 'description' : 'some text for radio1'},
    {"id": 2, 'name' : 'radio2', 'description' : 'some text for radio2'},
    {"id": 3, 'name' : 'radio3', 'description' : 'some text for radio3'}

  ];
});
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OnHXect37Phij9VAB0ET

You need to set the value to the whole "list" object with **ng-value**, no need for an additional flag.

Comment: Thanx... i figured that one... but is it possible to get the results without using value attribute... I have used it for some other purpose...

Comment: how can I pass the value as an object? it is not passed as an object right now...

Comment: Well, you can still use it for the other purpose. If you want "id" then keep using {{list}} for the value attribute, and when you need the id you can get it from $scope.radioModValue.id - makes sense?

Comment: To pass the value as an object you need to set radioModValue to an object of type list --> $scope.radioModValue = $scope.lists[0] for example.

Comment: $scope.radioModValue.id return an empty value...
http://plnkr.co/edit/h3jgs5XPYQ7eXTDvdCxm?p=preview

Comment: I thought it worked but it is not working... can you please check the updated plnkr... i have updated it as ur suggestion..

Comment: Well, I guess I'll update my answer :) you need to use "ng-value" instead of "value" to bind to an object: ng-value="list" without the curly braces; this way you'll be able to access id through $scope.radioModValue.id and set the value through $scope.radioModValue = $scope.lists[0] - I hope that helps. :)

Comment: Here is an updated Plunker to make it easier for you:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OnHXect37Phij9VAB0ET?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `listActive` variable in your scope and bind it to the option:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.listActive" value="{{list}}">
```

[Here is a sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/LaWMOxp5FUUzcLlTwWKk?p=preview)

Comment: it returns all the list. I only need the one that is selected.

Comment: I saw that if we put console.log($scope.lists[1]); in your solution... it gives only one object... but it is constant...

Comment: I updated the sample. Should serve your requirement now.

Comment: it does not provide all the information... I need all the id, description and name...

i have to add these information to another array later on...

Comment: that just requires to set `value="{{list}}` - see update