# How to use an object as ng-value of a radio button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Is there any way to use an object for ng-value of a radio button?

Imagine you have a radio button whose ng-model is an object, like this:

```
modelObject: {val:'', text:''}
```

And this would be the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="data.modelObject" ng-value=""/>
```

Is there a way to do something like the following (obviously it doesn't work)

```
<input type="radio" model="data.modelObject" ng-value="val:option.id, text:option.text"/>
```

?
Thanks

I know I can use the ng-change directive. I'm just wondering if what I am asking it's possible, it would be very smart

EDIT:
as requested in the comments, I am giving a bit of extra info on my setup.

I want to save in the model both the value of the button and its label. So let's say I have an array in my controller called impactOptions and a ng-repeat directive to create the buttons:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in impactOptions" >
    <input type="radio" ng-model="data.modelObject.val" id="rbGroup{{option.id}} ng-value="option.id"/>
    <label for="rbGroup{{option.id}}">{{option.text}}</label>
</div>
```

The problem with this setup is that in that way I'm only saving the value of the button, while I would like to also save it's label. I really need it later.

I'm looking for a way to do something like this

```
<input type="radio" model="data.modelObject" ng-value="val:option.id, text:option.text"/>
```

Comment: I feel like you should use `ng-change` to call a function in your controller, which sets the `val` and `text` appropriately (although I'm not sure what `option` is)

Comment: @Ian this is the way I'm following now, but I was wondering if it's possible what I am asking, it would speed up the thing a LOT

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't be smart - rather confusing (I still don't know are the `val` and `text` proprrties supposed to be used). Why not create a directive ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem well, I don't know if it's going to be smart, but it would be very useful for the setup I have. About the directive, I've just started with Angular, and it is probably going to be a bit overwhelming....

Comment: @ExpertSystem I've already written my first directive, to create a "reusable" component, but in this case every radio button group will have slightly different attributes, so maybe writing a directive would be very complex

Comment: @Sr.Richie: If you gave more jnfo on what exactly you are trying to achieve, we might be able to come up with something simple and smart.

Answer (score 5):

You can have an object as the value in `ng-value`:

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="modelObject" ng-value="{val:1, text:'text'}"/>
    <p>>{{modelObject|json}}<</p>
</div>
```

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Dgsx/1/)

The values in `ng-value` can also be dynamic as well per request:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="opt={id: 1, text: 'some text'}">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="modelObject" ng-value="{val:opt.id, text:opt.text}"/>
    <p>>{{modelObject|json}}<</p>
</div>
```

[updated example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Dgsx/2/)

Comment: Thx for your help, but is there any way to have the values of the properties not hardcoded? If i try to something like: {val:option.id, text:option.text} angular crashes. Please look at the edit in my question to see exactly the scenario. Thanks again, is the second time you're helping me with angular :)

Comment: of course that is possible (http://jsfiddle.net/7Dgsx/2/) `opt` is defined via `ng-init` so I didn't need to create a controller

Comment: thank you again. I don't understand where the problem is. If I try to use {val:opt.id, text:opt.text}, it crashes. I can use {val:{{option.id}} }, but if I try to use {val:{{option.id}}, text:{{option.text}}}, it crashes again. Sorry, I'm a very n00b with angular

Comment: No problem, the first part looks good, but could cause issues if you have not defined the option object. You can set that object like I did via ng-unit, or in the controller, which is suggested... $scope.option = {id:5, text: 'abc'};

Comment: option is obviously defined in the ng-repeat directive, as you can see in the question code.... Argh!

Comment: You are correct, my response was from my phone, just trying to help. Take a look at this plnkr as it shows this working: http://plnkr.co/edit/XWHldn8bcVGyCjaWd7z3?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-value="option"`:

```
<input type="radio" model="data.modelObject" ng-value="option"/>
```

When you need `id` you can have it from `$scope.option.id` and when you need `text` you can access it from `$scope.option.text`. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543917/get-all-values-when-button-is-pressed/23544955#23544955). Does this work for your case?